# DKIM body hash in python

Tags: python, dkim

I'm thinking this should be easy, but I just can't get the body hashsum right for multipart MIME e-mails. My code doesn't work so I just included a simple example of what I'm doing (I'm supplying a file with a full e-mail, headers and all):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import email
import sys
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
import hashlib

mail = email.message_from_bytes(open(sys.argv[1], "rb").read())
body = str(mail.get_payload())

canonicalized_body = body.strip().encode() + b"\r\n"
print("SHA256\t:", b64encode(hashlib.sha256(canonicalized_body).digest()))
print("SHA1\t:", b64encode(hashlib.sha1(canonicalized_body).digest()))
```

Anyone familiar with this? Goy any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get the body hashsum right"? What is wrong with this code? Why do you think it's wrong? What are you expecting the code to do or output? What does it do instead?

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of `str(mail.get_payload())`? I'm almost sure that it simply returns the string representation of the underlying object and doesn't actually decode the bytes in the payload

Comment: @ForceBru The "get_payload" parses out the body and strips the headers for me, but I've been fiddling around so much with this now I hardly know what I'm doing anymore. It does hash the message body, but the body hash doesn't match the body hash in the DKIM header, so I must be parsing the body wrong before hashing it.